# Request an audio file via curl in PHP and download it

Tags: php, curl

I have 2 Linux servers, server1 and server2, basically I need that in PHP via curl server1 requests an audio file "file.mp3" from server2 and that it receives the request and in response sends me the audio file "file.mp3" , then on server1 it should be able to receive that file as a response and place it in the folder. I can use curl to connect the 2 servers and have server2 respond to me but I have not found a way to send and receive an audio file, thank you.

servidor1:

```
$url = "servidor2/tts/solicitar_audio.php";
$data = array(
        'text' => "file.mp3",
        'idioma' => "es"
);

    $postdata = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//print_r ($result);
$data = json_decode($result,true);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

servidor2: /tts/solicitar_audio.php

```
$rec=$_SERVER;
$json_params=file_get_contents("php://input");
##Datos recibidos
$decoded_params = json_decode($json_params,true);
$text=$decoded_params['text'];
$idioma=$decoded_params['idioma'];

$file=$text;

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
```

Request an audio file and can download it when you get the response via curl.